# Is it possible to return HTML (instead of JS) data by using a remote link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1 and I would like to know if it is possible to make a `:remote` link to require HTML data as response. That is, I have the following code

```
link_to "Title", url, :remote => true
```

and when I click the link then, on response success, the response code is JS data but I would like to return HTML data, maybe something as the [`jQuery.ajax([settings])`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) method allows by setting `dataType: 'html'`.

In other words, when the above link is clicked then it triggers the `format.js` (in a `respond_to do |format| ... end` block) of my controller but I would like to make it to trigger the `format.html`.

If it is possible, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want html response then why you want to use ajax?

Comment: It is because I would like to simply retrieve HTML through AJAX. For example, a use case is: when the link is clicked then retrieve and display a image.

Comment: In your case you need to render a partial containing your image. It will still be an ajax and not html.

Comment: @user2675613 XHR can retrieve JS or HTML just fine. It is up to the *server* to return the expected data and the *client* to handle the returned data. (Prior to wide adoption of JSON and rich client-side scripting, this was actually the conventional way to use AJAX: returning HTML applied with `innerHTML`.)

Comment: @Backo It seems like "all" one would need to do is adapt the Unobtrusive JavaScript Driver applied to simply make an appropriate "html" request (for whatever your goal is) and apply the response.

Comment: Regarding you first comment, what is the expected data (now)? For the second, what is the state of facts (now)? N.B.: With "now" I mean "at this time", both in the Rails context and in the "general" context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to require HTML code as response to an AJAX request you should add the `:data => { :type => :html }` to the `link_to` statement, this way:

```
link_to "Title", url, :remote => true, :data => { :type => :html }
```

The Rails `jquery_ujs` is aware of how to handle that.