# Some questions on Unobtrusive JavaScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, unobtrusive-javascript

I am using Ruby on Rails and I heard of “[Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)” (UJS). After (but even before) [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942251/is-it-possible-to-return-html-instead-of-js-data-by-using-a-remote-link), I ask myself:

1. Are there common-used patterns, rules, practices or techniques in order to respond pragmatically to JavaScript and HTML AJAX requests? If there are, what are those? For example, what responses should be returned? What kind of data? Is there a standard?
2. Practically speaking, how should my controller `respond_to` (à la Rails) depend on the request format? That is, how should my application respond with `format.js`, `format.html` or `format.whatever` in controllers when using the Rails framework?
3. About the previous matters, what is the solution of the Rails community and / or of the “general” public? What do you use?

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax**

I don't know any patterns, but we take a "per feature" stance -

You'll have different use cases for different features. In the most part, you can handle these using the `remote: true` option ([which just uses the ajax handler in UJS](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/8539e604ecbd34dbdcc1795cc345fbc43f2c256e/src/rails.js#L82)), which will allow you to either capture the response with `.on("ajax:success"` in your asset JS, or by using a `.js.erb` file in the backend

The bottom line is we do what will produce the least amount of code. We always look at it from the perspective of future development - in the future, will you get confused with what we're doing, or will it be the logical way?

I suppose we could probably find a more structured way of handling this, but with the varying amounts of data coming back, we prefer to handle each feature in its own way

--

**Code**

I would personally put code efficiency & focus functionality first

Instead of trying to make a pattern to fit all cases, I'd look at what you're trying to achieve, and creating code to get it to work. If you can refactor after that, great! Otherwise, I'd invest my energy into getting functionality working